# AngularJs: Show version number from either git or bower

Tags: angularjs, git, bower

I have created an Angular application where I want to show the current version number of my application on screen. Currently I have implemented it as a constant:

```
application
    .constant('constants', {
        VERSION: '1.1.2'
    });
```

But this will require me to update the constant on every new version.
I use bower and git and I was wondering if there was any way to get the version number as a variable from one of these packages dynamically?

Comment: You are hardcoding your version, and this may be not the best solution. Version doesn't belong to code, it's and attribute.

Comment: In Git there are tags, often used to mark certain release versions. But one has to manually create tags.

Comment: Do you have a backend, e.g. NodeJS? Then it is possible to provide the version via the backend, if I understand you right.

Comment: I think you can do something with grunt

Comment: I actually use a php REST back-end. Also git with release tags...

Comment: @Nick Volynkin: I know... Hence the question... :-)

Comment: what's in your bower.json file? can you use this as a possible resource?

Comment: @Shehryar, yes. Version number is also in my bower.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is to use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and [gulp-ng-constant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-constant) plugin. It will automate your release workflow, write version of your app in Angular constant service.

- Install Gulp
- Install gulp-ng-constant
- Write your gulp task like following and run it `gulp constants`:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ngConstant = require('gulp-ng-constant');

gulp.task('constants', function() {
  // get version from bower file
  var bower = require('./bower.json');
  // set version to ng contants
  var constants = { version: bower.version };

  return ngConstant({
      constants: constants,
      stream: true,
      name: 'app.constants'
    })
    // save ngConstant.js to src/app/
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/app'));
});
```

It will generate angular.module for you as following:

```js
angular.module("app.constants", [])
  .constant("version", "0.0.1")
```

And the last step you need is to inject your generated constant service in your main app:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['app.constants']);
```

You may be also interested in use [gulp-bump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bump/) task to automatically increment your app version before it will be added to ng-constant service.

See following tutorial: [Versioning Your Angular Application with Gulp](http://blogs.ibs.com/2015/09/08/versioning-your-angular-application-with-gulp/)

Comment: Ty for this answer. It's a beautiful and elegant solution!

Comment: can't take it from packagaje.json?

Comment: @SebastiánRojas, yep. Change following in code above. `var bower = require('./bower.json');`