# get app version in angular.js

Tags: xml, angularjs, cordova

I am trying to find a way to get in my controller the current app version which is in the config.xml Phonegap file.

This file is located in the project's root (same level as Gruntfile, bower.json ...etc.)

I can use the phonegap plugin "AppVersion", but my app can also be used as a webapp, so I need to find something else.

Is there any angularjs library who can do this ?

Edit: The app version is in bower.json and package.json as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access a value from a Phonegap plugin in an Angular controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350842/how-to-access-a-value-from-a-phonegap-plugin-in-an-angular-controller)

Answer (score -1):

Solution is to use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and [gulp-ng-constant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-constant) plugin. It will automate your release workflow: write version of your app in Angular constant service.

- Install [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)
- Install [gulp-ng-constant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-constant)
- Create `gulpfile.js` and add following task in it:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var ngConstant = require('gulp-ng-constant');

    gulp.task('constants', function() {
      // get version from bower file
      var bower = require('./bower.json');
      // set version to ng contants
      var constants = { version: bower.version };

      return ngConstant({
          constants: constants,
          stream: true
        })
        // save ngConstant.js to src/app/
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/app'));
    });
```

Now you can run `gulp constants` task and it will generate following code in `src/app/ngConstant.js` with version set in your `bower.json`:

```
angular.module("ngConstants", [])
  .constant("version", "0.0.1")
;
```

Include this file and add `ngConstants` as a dependency in your app definition and freely access your app version in controllers and views:

```
var app = angular.module('yourNgAppName', ['ngConstants']);

app.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', 'version', SomeController]);

function SomeController($scope, version)
{
  $scope.version = version;
}
```

---

See answer on similar question:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/30421938/angularjs-show-version-number-from-either-git-or-bower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421938/angularjs-show-version-number-from-either-git-or-bower/35777950#35777950)

---

Or the following tutorial: [Versioning Your Angular Application with Gulp](http://blogs.ibs.com/2015/09/08/versioning-your-angular-application-with-gulp/)